# Using https://dev:8080/ or another CNAME in browser without security error

Tags: iis, dns, openssl, certificate, cname

Here the machine is laptop.mylocaldomain.net, while dev is a CNAME record aliasing the laptop host from the local DNS server. Both respond to pings and give the same IP address as expected.

Whether it's Firefox, Chrome, or Edge though, if I navigate to https://dev:8080/ running on IIS from a laptop with a self-signed certificate I get a **Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue** error and cannot connect to the site, but if I use https://dev.mylocaldomain.net:8080/ which is the same IP address say I get a **Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead** warning and I can proceed to the website.

Also https://laptop:8080/ gives the same **Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead** warning and I can proceed to the website. Only the CNAME https://dev:8080/ doesn't work.

Cert creation script:

```
#/bin/sh
sudo openssl genrsa -out LocalDevelopmentCert.key 2048
sudo openssl req -new -key LocalDevelopmentCert.key -sha256 -days 3650 -out LocalDevelopmentCert.csr -config openssl.cnf
sudo openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in LocalDevelopmentCert.csr -signkey LocalDevelopmentCert.key -out LocalDevelopmentCert.crt -extensions v3_req -extfile openssl.cnf
sudo openssl pkcs12 -name "Local Development IIS Cert" -export -out LocalDevelopmentCert.pfx -inkey LocalDevelopmentCert.key -in LocalDevelopmentCert.crt
```

Alt Names section of openssl.cnf:

```
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = *.mylocaldomain.net
DNS.2 = dev
IP.1 = 192.168.XXX.XXX # <- IP address of dev laptop
```

I've tried setting the CN to various permutations of addresses like dev, dev.mylocaldomain.net, etc. None of them seem to work in the browsers.

How can I get https://dev:8080/ working?

**UPDATE 1:**

Jesux Manager SSL diagnostic report section:

```
BINDING: https *:8080:
SSLCertHash: b10671ac592ea5363db0a189fa72180d49ff1956
SSL Flags: None
Testing EndPoint: 127.0.0.1
Cannot find certificate with thumbprint b10671ac592ea5363db0a189fa72180d49ff1956 in store My.
```

There isn't a store called "My" on Windows 10. I checked every store in MMC for both the Current User and Local Computer to ensure there are no duplicates.

**Update 2:**

I used the following method to generate a self-signed cert that does report as working in Jexus Manager and its properties show that the certificate is OK.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
x509_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = dn

[dn]
C = MyCountry
ST = MyState
L = MyLocality
O = Local Org
OU = Local Org Unit
emailAddress = admin@mylocaldomain.net
CN = *.mylocaldomain.net

[v3_req]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = dev.mylocaldomain.net
DNS.2 = dev
DNS.3 = prod.mylocaldomain.net
DNS.4 = prod
DNS.5 = www
DNS.6 = laptop
DNS.7 = desktop
DNS.8 = localhost
">openssl.current.cnf

sudo openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout localcert.key -days 3650 -out localcert.crt -config openssl.current.cnf
sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -out localcert.pfx  -inkey localcert.key -in localcert.crt -name "Local Dev Certificate"
```

It works fine as a self-signed cert Edge and Chrome, but not in Firefox. Does Firefox require you to be your own CA for local development?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: I checked it out, SSL diagnostic reports this: "Cannot find certificate with thumbprint b10671ac592ea5363db0a189fa72180d49ff1956 in store My.", but there is a cert with that thumbprint in Personal, I'm not sure about the "My" part. I don't have a certificate store that starts with "My."

Comment: I am looking into running my own CA, but wondering if I need an alternate configuration to specify subjectAltName on the CA's pem.

Comment: If you edit the question to include the report (mask out private information first), then more advice can be provided. You cannot install a server certificate to your personal account, as IIS only looks for certificates in the computer account. That's why SSL Diag tells you things are wrong.

Comment: @LexLi ok that's updated. Everything was installed to the Local Computer account btw. I can see any pfx I add in IIS, but it's coming up as an invalid certificate.

Comment: @LexLi take a look at the Update 2 above. I used a different script to generate a self-signed cert and pfx through OpenSSL with subject alt names. It works in the Jexus Manager SSL Diagnostic and reports as OK. However, it's not working in Firefox but does seem to in Chrome and Edge now.

Comment: Then you are almost done. Firefox is different from Chrome and Edge, as it requires you to do extra steps, https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/setting-certificate-authorities-firefox so as to extend Windows integration.

Comment: Yep, it worked after setting security.enterprise_roots.enabled to true, looks like you don't need to set up a CA after all.

Comment: Second script was found here: https://dylanbeattie.net/2017/08/07/generating-self-signed-https.html

Comment: Then you can summarize what you learned as an answer and accept it.